# What does the & operator do in the spotlight's calculator?

Tags: spotlight

When using the spotlight's calculator function, I noticed that & can be used as an operator. For example:

```
5 & 4 = 4
5 & 3 = 1
5 & 2 = 0
5 & 1 = 1
```

My question is what is this operator?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a bitwise AND operator.
Looking at your first example:
5 & 4 = 1.
101 (5 decimal)
100 (4 decimal)
Answer has a 1 only in positions that have a 1 in both operands, which is just the most significant bit in this case:
100 (4 decimal)

Comment: So why is `1 & -1 = 0` and `1  & -2 = 0` also?

Comment: @roydbt It's because of [Two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement): In it -1 is all 1s and -2 is all 1s except for the last digit.

Comment: @cachius So why isn’t the answer for the first one 1?

Comment: Good catch! I have no idea. You can ask a new followup question.